A Definition of a Lebesgue Inner Measure
The Lebesgue inner measure is often not defined, for reasons explained here. Yet Tao, in his book An Introduction to Measure Theory, defines the Lebesgue inner measure for a bounded set $E$ as follows:
$$m_*(E) := m(A) - m^*(A\setminus E)$$
for any elementary set $A$ containing $E$, where $m^*$ is the Lebesgue outer measure.

Such section left me wondering if we could define the Lebesgue inner measure for an arbitrary set $E$ as follows:
$$m_*(E) = \sup\{ m(A) - m^*(A\setminus E) : \text{ $A$ is an elementary set }\}.$$
Would such a definition be 'correct'? In particular, are the following equivalent?

$E$ is Lebesgue measurable i.e. $E$ is Carathéodory measurable in $\mathcal{\mathbb{R}^n}$.
$m_*(E) = m^*(E)$.


I guess if $E$ is Lebesgue measurable and $A$ is any bounded elementary set then both $A\setminus E$ and $A\cap E$ are Lebesgue measurable and $m(A)-m^(A\setminus E)=m^(A\cap E)$, so the supremum in the expression for $m_(E)$ equals $m^(E)$.
